# Setting/finding velocity vector for circular orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

I'm attempting to simulate a core and some stars. The core is situated at some position $\mathbf{r}_{core}$ and it's surrounded by stars. My issue is setting the initial velocity of these stars so that it will fall into a circular orbit.

Going off my homework and guidance, the magnitude of the velocity of the stars is $v_{star} = \frac{\sqrt{m_{core}r_{star}}}{r}$ where $r = |\mathbf{r_{star}} - \mathbf{r}_{core}|$.

We're using dimensionless units so G=1.

Now, I know that the velocity is tangential to the star's position vector (or maybe just tangential to the separation vector) but I'm lost about going how to solve for the velocity's components. I tried using the using the dot product and magnitude to solve for one of the components but I wasn't able to isolate $v_x$ or $v_y$. I got this far:

$$r/r_{star} = -v_x (v_{star}^2 - v_x^2)$$

I've searched online for help but everything switches to polar coordinates or does $x=rcos(\theta)$ etc.

How do I solve for the velocity components??

Edits;

Comment: Your equation for $v_{\text{star}}$ doesn't make sense dimensionally as the left side is a velocity and the right side has dimensions of $\sqrt{\frac{M}{L}}$ (M is units of mass and L is units of length). Unless of course $m_1$ stands for something other than mass.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I'm using dimensionless units so G=1. Made edits